# How to add secure FTP capabilities to a .NET application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, ftp, sftp

I'm rewriting an in-house client-server application as a .NET MVC application. It needs to send and receive files via secure FTP. The original application was client-server and used MOVEit Freely to do SFTP. Is there a library or product I can use to do it from within .NET?

Comment: You might want to edit the subject to say SFTP vs FTP, two very different animals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnet/overview.html

Answer (score 2):

Just use the built-in [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) and [FtpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebresponse.aspx) classes.

Comment: Watch out for the folks who are selling something apparently.  They'll mod you to hell.  +1 to get you out of the negative.

Comment: There are a lot of comments above stating that they don't offer SFTP support - those comments would be true!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [SharpSSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpssh/), I know they have support for sftp, don't know how hard it will be to write the server side.

Answer (score 2):

Our [Rebex File Transfer Pack](http://www.rebex.net/file-transfer-pack/) supports both variants of Secure FTP - the SFTP and FTPS (FTP/SSL).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to pay anything, you can easily use the built-in [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) for vanilla FTP and FTPES (explicit FTP with SSL).  For FTPS (implicit FTP+SSL), I recommend [Alex FTPS Client](http://ftps.codeplex.com/).  And finally, for SFTP (FTP over SSH), you can use [SharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/category/SharpSSH.aspx).  This method isn't for everyone - it's really just for the cheap skate.  But, I've been using this combo for all my data transfer needs in a production environment and it works great.  The products are stale, but the protocols are stable, so who cares.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [edtFTPnet/PRO](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/overview.html), which offers full support for SFTP in .NET.

You might also want to take a look at [CompleteFTP](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/completeftp/overview.html), which is a fast, compact SFTP server for Windows platforms (it also supports FTP and FTPS).

I might add that using the term "Secure FTP" can be rather confusing. It can mean SFTP, which is a secure file transfer protocol that runs over SSH. Or it can mean FTPS, which is basically standard FTP commands running over an SSL connection.

Answer (score 0):

This is native in .NET. The classes you want resides in the System.Net namespace. Take a look at FtpWebRequest and FtpWebResponse classes. Happy coding :)

Comment: I don't think there's SFTP support is there?

Comment: No, they don't have Secure FTP support.

Comment: There's support for FTPES (explicit ftp + ssl).  The security mechanism wasn't specified by the author, and this is plenty secure after the initial connection negotiation.

Answer (score 0):

I was involved in creating MOVEit Freely.  It never had support for SFTP over SSH - it only had support for FTP/S.  Its original role was to be a "drop-in" command-for-command replacement of Microsoft's FTP.exe client - with extra support for SSL/TLS.

MOVEit Freely was originally built on top of a Dundas FTP/S stack, but we heavily modifed the original source code as FTP/S evolved.  (We got in a bit early.)   These days Dundas is focused on Dashboard components and the license agreement we signed with Dundas said that we'd never publish a standalone FTP/S component based on their code.  (That's standard for that kind of OEM license.)  In other words, I'd check out one of the Windows-based recommendations above.  (I recommend components from \n software, and also like the Rebex offering on Windows.)